# Updating views issue

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I think I'm having a problem with ViewControllers being loaded at the start of the application. I have two ViewControllers controlled by a TabBarController. On ViewA I have a button and when the button is clicked it uses a notification to call a method in ViewB to update a label on ViewB. But the label doesn't change until I have clicked on ViewB to be displayed on the screen at least once. I was wondering if there was a way for the label to be updated when I clicked the button without having to click on ViewB prior.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, IBOutlet properties are set to nil until the view is actually loaded. So if you try to set the text of an IBOutlet label before the view is actually loaded, you will just be sending messages to nil.

You could try calling loadView on ViewControllerB after you initialize it to load the view from the nib, although the Apple Documentation says that you're not supposed to call this method directly. You could also maybe create a property in ViewControllerB where you set the updated label properties, and use this property to set the IBOutlet in viewControllerB's viewWillAppear.

I would recommend something different; saving what ever you want the label in viewB to be set somewhere accesible from ViewControllerb, and then setting the label in ViewControllerB's viewWillAppear. For example you could save it in NSUserDefaults:

```
NSString *viewBLabelText = @"ViewB Label Text";
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:viewBLabelText forKey:@"ViewBLabelText"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

and then in the viewWillAppear of ViewControllerB:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.labelProperty.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"ViewBLabelText"];
```